# jquery jquery-1.9.0 set div to display:none when I trying to use toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am learning jQuery by reading the book  (very good book by the way.)

When I do the tutorial 5 exercise, I notice that jQuery always set  to display:none AUTOMATICALLY using jquery-1.9.0. When I change to the lower version (eg 1.8.3 or 1.6.3), they seem to work well. Wondering if you experienced same issue? Have you worked it out with version 1.9.0?

Below is my code. You can also download it from (http://sawmac.com/js2e/   Chapter 5/complete_faq.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A One Page Faq</title>
    <link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        h2
        {
            background: url(../_images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
            padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            h2.close
            {
                background-image: url(../_images/close.png);
            }

        .answer
        {
            margin-left: 25px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.answer').hide();
            $('.main h2').toggle(
                   function () {
                       $(this).next('.answer').slideDown();
                       $(this).addClass('close');
                   },
                   function () {
                       $(this).next('.answer').fadeOut();
                       $(this).removeClass('close');
                   }
               ); // end toggle
        }); // end ready
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>
                Missing<br>
                Manual</i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="main">
                <h1>A One Page FAQ</h1>
                <h2>I've heard that JavaScript is the long-lost fountain of youth. Is this true?</h2>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Why, yes it is! Studies prove that learning JavaScript freshens the mind and extends life span by several hundred years. (Note: some scientists disagree with these claims.)</p>
                </div>
                <h2>Can JavaScript really solve all of my problems?</h2>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Why, yes it can! It's the most versatile programming language ever created and is trained to provide financial management advice, life-saving CPR, and even to take care of household pets.</p>
                </div>
                <h2>Is there nothing JavaScript <em>can&#8217;t</em> do?</h2>
                <div class="answer">
                    <p>Why, no there isn&#8217;t! It&#8217;s even able to write its own public relations-oriented Frequently Asked Questions pages. Now that&#8217;s one smart programming language!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you see this http://jquery.com/download/ it says that you should use _jQuery Migrate plugin if you are upgrading from older versions of jQuery_

Comment: Thanks @asifsid88 I download the Migrate plugin and 1.9.1 works well with migrate plugin. It is a work around. However I did not upgrate from older version of jQuery, I want to just 1.9.1 directly, why it's not work well?

Answer (score 2):

The [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

> **[.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)**
>
> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions" signature of `.toggle()`. It should not be confused with the "change the visibility of an element" of `.toggle()` which is not deprecated. **The former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential for modularity in the library.** The [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#jquery-migrate-migrate-older-jquery-code-to-jquery-19) can be used to restore the functionality.

Although, it is better if you stop using altogether.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, your answer is helpful.

Comment: @Xavier, no problem. Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer in your questions. Doing this will help other people with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As other answer from `Alexander` mentioned that `.toggle()` has been removed from `jQuery version 1.9.0+` but if you use `migrate plugin` that would work for sure.

add this migrate plugin script below jQuery if you want to use `jQuery 1.9.0+` :

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js'></script>
```